# In yii how do I log every user's requests or actions for audit and analysis

Tags: logging, yii, audit-trail

I want to log every visitor's behavior

- authenticated user or guest
- visiting ip
- time
- sequence of the requests
- database read/write (if any)
- log out time (for authenticated user) , or session over time (for guest)

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There are readily available extensions for this 
I have used this extension for most of your use cases

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/audittrail/

or the newer version is here

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/audittrail2/

For 2. you would need to create some client side code js as well,

For 6. Writes can be captured by auditTrail, generally DB reads i don't advise capturing, as it generates a lot of data and causes significant overhead.